# Is there a way to make List.addAll sort elements?Need it for search

Tags: java, guava

I have to alter an existing code, said code retrieves a list of Objects Obj:

```
public class Obj{
   ...fields...
   private String label; //the field the search is performed on
}
```

from a service call and puts it inside of an ArrayList:
     List retrievedList = ..service call ...
    finalList.addAll(retrievedList);

Subsequently some clients can ask me to find an Obj with a certain label, right now the search is poorly made like this:

```
for(Obj o :finalList){
     if(o.getLabel().equals(label){
       return o;
     else
        ...
```

There are about 100.000 Obj instances in that list so the search is not efficient at all.

My idea is to first make the Obj class implement a Comparator based on the label, then make so that the addAll method respects that comparator thus ordering objects based on the label field.
Subsequently implements something like a quickSort or use some more efficient construct, if Guava provides any.
Have you any ideas?

Comment: How about Collections.sort(yourlist, new yourComparator()) ?

Comment: Use the contains method of that list to find an object. You will have to override hashcode and equals. Determine a "business (primary) key" (not a database id) like "invoice number or "email" which is unique to your objects and use this in hashcode and equals.

Comment: @user3232446  - He will have to call sort after every modification to the list (or worse, before he queries). Not efficient.

Comment: Store it in an HashMap with your label as a key

Comment: HashSet  fits what you need.

Comment: I'm looking into HashSet...do I need to implement a comparator in this case as well, right?

Comment: If your List is dynamic you can use Insertionssort Algorithm, otherwise use Collection.sort and searsch using contains Method.

Answer (score 0):

The guava provided [TreeMultiset](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html) will fit your needs. This collection type supports adding multiple values of an element (in your case I am assuming multiple objects can have the same label) with a custom comparator and it implements the Collection interface. It is also a sorted collection and add/remove/search operations are very efficient as it uses a tree data structure.

Searching for items can be done using the [subMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html#subMultiset(E,%20com.google.common.collect.BoundType,%20E,%20com.google.common.collect.BoundType)) method which will return all elements within a specified range.